# this.backPressed is not a function

Tags: react-native

I implemented it in sample , it works but in my main project it's displaying error message that backPressed is not a function.

```
backPressed = () => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      //Put All Your Code Here, Which You Want To Execute After Some Delay Time.
      BackHandler.exitApp();
    }, 3000);
  };

componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.backPressed);
  }

componentDidMount() {
      BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.backPressed);  

}
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    const { userdata } = nextProps.UserDetailReducer;

    const { UpdatingFailure } = nextProps.UpdateUserImageReducer;

    if (UpdatingFailure) {
      return {
        avatarSource: ""
      };
    }

    if (userdata.kenkoScore != "" && userdata.kenkoScore > 0) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        AsyncStorage.setItem("SCORE_FETCHED", "Yes");
        nextProps.navigation.navigate("TabNavigation");
      }, 100);
      return null;
    } else {
        ***this.backPressed();***
    }

    if (userdata) {
      return { userDetail: userdata };
    }

    return null;
  }
```

In **componentDidMount** it is working but in **getDerivedStateFromProps** not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getDerivedStateFromProps` is [static](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) so `this` refers to the class itself, not an instance of the class.

Make `backPressed` static to call it from `getDerivedStateFromProps`. You'll also need to update `componentWillUnmount` and `componentDidMount` to `ComponentName.backPressed` or `this.constructor.backPressed`. Note that making `backPressed` static means you won't be able to access `this` for props or state in the future.

Comment: class ScoreFetched extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

Comment: still unable to call from function

Comment: `static backPressed() { ... }` and `ScoreFetched.backPressed` are what you should use.